# Replicate GetKey & GetKeyDown like a UI button

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make a UI Button works like the key presses Unity Input methods, but I can't realize on my own how to make this. I tried using the button event and eventTrigger but it doesn't work like it suppose GetKey and Getkeydown works.
Any ideas? thanks in advanced.

Comment: what you exactly ooking for?

Comment: @virtouso mobile controller, but I need to know if the button is just pressed (GetKeyDown) or held (GetKey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need **OnClick** and **EventTrigger** events including **OnPOinterEnter** and **OnPointerExit**.

for GetKeyDown() just use OnClick(). you can set it in inspector or just add your event like link below:

https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html

if You look for **GetKey** you have to define a bool Variable. and make it True on **OnPOinterEnter** and make it false on **OnPointerExit**

just assign KeyDown and KeyUp methods to these events.

```
  Bool KeyIsDown;

void keyDown(){KeyIsDown=true;}
void keyUp(){KeyIsDown=false;}
    void Update()
    {
    if(KeyIsDown)
    {
    // everything like GetKey()
    }
    }
```